# How can I rewrite this blade if statement using a ternary operator?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How can I rewrite this if statement using a ternary operator?

```
@if($headerStyle->header_bg_color == NULL)

@else

style="background-color: {{ $headerStyle->header_bg_color }};"

@endif
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ternary for that. You can try something like this:
`@if($headerStyle->header_bg_color !== NULL) style="background-color: {{ $headerStyle->header_bg_color }};"@endif`

Answer (score 1):

Using Ternary operator:

```
style={{$headerStyle->header_bg_color? 'background-color: '.$headerStyle->header_bg_color: null}}
```

PHP evaluates `null, false, 0, and ''` as false using them on a conditional statement.

So you don't need to strict check if the `$headerStyle->header_bg_color` is null or not.

If you don't want the style tag to be showing at all then

```
{!! $headerStyle->header_bg_color? 'style:"background-color: "'.$headerStyle->header_bg_color:'' !!}
```

You need to use {!! !!} to prevent blade escaping `" "` quotation marks